# After search form submit there is no search parameter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a search form like this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Search", "Items", null, null)" method="POST">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="q" value="some search term">
                     <input type="hidden" name="city" value="london" />    
                </form>
```

This invoke "`Search`" action method:

```
public ActionResult Search(string city, string q)
        {
            ...
            return View(model);
        }
```

Here I receive both values and search gone fine.
**But** URL in my browser is:

```
http://localhost/mysite/item/Search?city=london
```

as you can see I am missing "q" parameter in URL.
What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form method is POST, so values are not sent via the query string. Change the POST to GET and you should see them.

Comment: That doesn't solve why `london` is still being sent through the GET parameters...

Comment: What is the URL of the page the search form is on? Perhaps it's coming from there?

Answer (score 1):

Input type for your search field needs to be Text, not Search.

Comment: I have change it to 'text' now and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to close the tag `<input ... />`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q" value="some search term" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my example:

Model:

```
public class SearchModel{
  public String City { get; set; }
  public String Q { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model SearchModel
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "Form"})) {
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.City)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Q)
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string city, string q)
{
  var model = new SearchModel {
       City = "london",
       Q = "some search term"
  };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
  //.....
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You need to discriminate between **HttpPost** and **HttpGet** :)